# Dictionary saving but overwriting last key entered

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having a difficult time trying to save and update a dictionary to a pickle file based off input. After running the command and entering a new show the dictionary never adds a new key and value. Why is that? I have followed a lot of posts for a month now and tried the basic ways on how to do this, but it always ends up being overwritten.

```
import pickle

user_settings = {'mjp3LhFUUS8ZM7zW8UV4tHTDyD4=': {'notify': {}}}
user_input = input('Command: ')

def changedict():
    if user_input == 'run':
        newshow = input("New show: ")
        user_notify = user_settings['mjp3LhFUUS8ZM7zW8UV4tHTDyD4=']['notify']
        print(user_notify)
        user_notify[newshow] = 242525
        pickle.dump(user_settings, open("save.p", "wb"))
        print(user_settings)
    elif user_input == 'read':
        readdict = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
        print(readdict)

    else:
        print('Not a command')

changedict()
```

When I run and add a new show I receive `{'mjp3LhFUUS8ZM7zW8UV4tHTDyD4=': {'notify': {'test': 242525}}}` but after running again and trying to add a new show I get `{'mjp3LhFUUS8ZM7zW8UV4tHTDyD4=': {'notify': {'test2': 242525}}}`. What I want is to do is get the dictionary to save like so `{'mjp3LhFUUS8ZM7zW8UV4tHTDyD4=': {'notify': {'test': 242525}, {'test2': 242525}}}`

Comment: Works for me.  What exactly is the issue?  How are you using this program, what output do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: The `userinput` is  a `function` and `variable` on the same time.

Comment: No, one is `userinput` and the other is `user_input` with a `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing when you say you are running the program again, you mean you are completely running the script again , using - `python <script.py>` .

Then the issue is that for each run of the program you are re-defining the user-settings dictionary as -

```
user_settings = {'mjp3LhFUUS8ZM7zW8UV4tHTDyD4=': {'notify': {}}}
```

If the user enters the command `run` , then you are only adding the user's input to this user_settings, you are not reading the dictionary from the file again.

So this would overwrite the dictioanry with what the user inputted.

You may want to set that only if you are unable to read it from the file.

Example -

```
import pickle

try:
    user_settings = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
except (IOError, pickle.UnpicklingError):
    user_settings = {'mjp3LhFUUS8ZM7zW8UV4tHTDyD4=': {'notify': {}}}
```

`IOError` - It would catch exception if the file - `save.p` does not exist.
`pickle.UnpicklingError` - It would catch exception if the file - `save.p` - does not contain correct pickled data.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed something so simple. I've got my code working now since I `pickle.load` before entering a new show. By the way I love your Stiens; Gate avatar. :) Thank You